# Simplifying a Partial Trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, kronecker-product

Given the following Partial Trace

\begin{equation}
P = \big( I \otimes \langle e_i| \big) \big[ A(B \otimes \mathcal{I} \big]^n \big( I \otimes | e_0 \rangle \big),
\end{equation}
where $dim(P) = 2 \times 2$, $dim(|e_j\rangle) = (2n+1) \times1$, $dim(I) = 2 \times2$, $dim(A) = (2n+1) \times(2n+1)$, $dim(B)=2\times2$, and $dim(\mathcal{I}) = 2n+1$.

My query is whether it is possible to use some tensor algebra to simplify this partial trace further?

Comment: Did you mean $I \otimes \langle e_i\rvert$? Note that transposing does not reverse the order of Kronecker product factors (unlike matrix product factors, whose order is reversed). BTW, you're missing a closing parenthesis for the opening one before $B$.

Comment: Thanks@celtschk. Corrected.

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret the product
$$
[A(B \otimes \mathcal I]
$$
Note that for the product $A(B \otimes \mathcal I)$ to make sense, we need $A$ to have size $(4n + 2) \times (4n \times 2)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the expression that you are trying to simplify is 
$$
P = \big( I \otimes \langle e_i| \big) \big[ A(B \otimes \mathcal{I}) \big]^n \big( I \otimes | e_i \rangle \big),
$$
where $A$ has size $(4n+2)\times (4n+2)$ and we are following the Einstein-summation convention.

There isn't too much you can do with this as written.  However, we can write
$$
A = \sum_{j,k=1}^{2} E_{jk} \otimes A_{jk}
$$
where $E_{ij} = |e_i \rangle \langle e_j|$.  With that, your expression becomes
$$
P = \big( I \otimes \langle e_i| \big) \big[ (E_{jk} \otimes A_{jk})(B \otimes \mathcal{I}) \big]^n \big( I \otimes | e_i \rangle \big)\\
= \big( I \otimes \langle e_i| \big) \big[ (E_{jk}B \otimes A_{jk}) \big]^n \big( I \otimes | e_i \rangle \big)\\
= \big( I \otimes \langle e_i| \big) [(E_{jk}B)^n \otimes (A_{jk}) ^n] \big( I \otimes | e_i \rangle \big)\\
= (E_{jk}B)^n \cdot \langle e_i |(A_{jk}) ^n|e_i \rangle.
$$
Write $E_{jk}B = xy^T$ where $x = (1,1)^T$ and $y = (B_{11} + B_{21}, B_{12} + B_{22})^T$.  We can rewrite the above as
$$
P = (xy^T)^n \cdot \langle e_i |(A_{jk}) ^n|e_i \rangle
\\ = (y^Tx)^{n-1} \cdot \sum_{j,k}\operatorname{tr}(A_{jk}^n) \cdot xy^T.
$$